# Angular, nested directive repeats, pass if parent is $last

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to trigger an event once all the repeats in this nested repeat are done. So I know you can do a $last, but I have no way of telling inside the inner repeat that it is on the $last in the parent repeat. So I have this

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="filter in filters.filters" repeat-directive-one filter="filter" update-filter="updateFilter">
</div>
</div>
```

Then inside repeat-directive-one looks like

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in filter.values | limitTo: filter.showMore ? filter.values.length : '5' track by $index" repeat-directive-two value="::item" update-filter="updateFilter" ng-if="!$last"></div>

<div ng-repeat="item in filter.values | limitTo: filter.showMore ? filter.values.length : '5' track by $index" repeat-directive-two value="::item" update-filter="updateFilter" ng-if="$last"checkbox-fix></div>
```

So what that does is if it is on the last item in that repeat it adds on the checkbox-fix directive to fix an issue. But if the upper repeat has 4 items, this fires 4 times so I would like something to the degree of

```
  ng-if="$last && parent.$last"
```

but that logic doesn't seem to be working as intended. I even tried to pass the parent last (boolean) as an isolate scope attr like (in repeat directive one)

```
   <div ng-repeat="filter in filters.filters" repeat-directive-one filter="filter" update-filter="updateFilter" last-property="$last">
```

but logging $scope.lastProperty returns nothing. So I would like a way to pass down some sort of flag that the parent repeat is $last. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Try using ng-if="$last && $parent.$last" instead of ng-if="$last && parent.$last"

Comment: @trevor that ended up doing the trick, it had to be if(elem.$parent.$parent.$last && elem.$last) inside the directive, 2 levels of parents because of the data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it based on @trevor 's advice like so :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in filter.values | limitTo: filter.showMore ? filter.values.length : '5' track by $index" repeat-directive-two value="::item" update-filter="updateFilter" checkbox-fix></div>
```

Stuck the checkbox-fix on the repeat (no need for 2 toggled via ng-if), and then inside the checkbox-fix directive I did like so :

```
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(elem, attr, tr) {
           if(elem.$parent.$parent.$last && elem.$last){
                //fixed!
           }
        }
    };
```

So elem.$last worked great, I had to check the data/structure a bit to realize I had to do elem.$parent.$parent.$last instead of just 1 level of parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to broadcast when the outerloop is complete and then the final loop of the inner should start watching the $last

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs" outer-loop>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" inner-loop></div>
</div>


angular.module('test').directive('outerLoop', function($rootScope){
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('outerLoopComplete');
        }   
    };
});

angular.module('test').directive('innerLoop', function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var outerLoopComplete = false;

        scope.$on('outerLoopComplete', function(){
            outerLoopComplete;
        });

        if(outerLoopComplete && $last){
            //inner loop complete
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

You can use ngInit to set the value of $last to a scope variable, you should be able to access this variable from the child scope directly and indirectly in the case of isolate scope.